# UNSIGNED NOT NULL mySql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was just wondering, do you have to put UNSIGNED NOT NULL after your foreign key(s) in the table? And what does UNSIGNED actually mean?

// Product table

```
id INT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
order_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
customer_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

// Customer table

```
id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
```

Do I have to have **UNSIGNED** after my foreign key or can I leave it out?

Also, does my primary key (*in the customer table*) have to be named the **SAME** as my foreign key (*in the Product table*) to be link, or how do I link them? I know I can use joins, but where do I do this in my php code or sql code? phpmyadmin or php code?

*This is for a wordpress plugin*

Any help appreciated, don't really understand this fully yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a 16bit int:

```
signed: -32,768 -> +32,767
unsigned: 0 -> 65,535
```

If you don't specify signedness or nullity, then the DB is free to choose its defaults for both, which is generally "signed" and allows nulls.

key names do **NOT** have to be the same in the parent and child records. But the definitions of the fields **DO** have to match exactly. If the definitions don't match, then the DB will forbid creation of the foreign key.

e.g.

```
create table parent (
   id int unsigned
);

create table child
   bad_fk int signed,       // bad FK. cannot have mixed signed/unsigned
   ok_fk  int unsigned,     // ok, data type definitions match exactly.
   horrible_fk  varchar(16) // total mismatch on type definitions
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers from both of you ,Marc B and AlienWebguy,this makes sense now!